# Is there a way to resolve c# in a typescript file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, typescript

Im trying to strip all the javascript out of an exisiting asp.net project and put it into typescript, but it typically fails with lines like:

```
<%=UiHelper.ControllerName %>grid = false;
```

I'm trying do dynamically generate variablenames in typescript based on c#values.

Is this possible?

Comment: no, you typically pass the name in the constructor or as an argument method to your typescript class.

Comment: you can pass JSON configuration object from c# as agrument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this generally would be to create a JavaScript configuration object in your C#, for example...

```
var config = {
    grid: false,
    other: 'etc'
};
```

And then tell your TypeScript application that this has already been declared:

```
interface Config {
    grid: boolean;
    other: string;
}

declare var config: Config;
```

In your case, it is complicated by the fact you are generating the variable names dynamically...

```
var config = {
    <%=UiHelper.ControllerName %>grid = false,
    <%=UiHelper.ControllerName %>other = 'etc'
};
```

This means you may not be able to predict names at compile time. If this is the case, you can use a dynamic configuration variable instead of a typed one:

```
declare var config: any;
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try this, :)